# Tab Layout example from Android Dev site

Tags: android

I'm trying to do this tab view example from [Android Examples](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), it works fine but I don't see the text (This is the ArtistsTab) in each tab that is set using the TextView. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Below are the main contents of my manifest file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SongsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Below is the content of OnCreate() method of the ArtistsActivity class

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Artists Tab");
        setContentView(textView);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you are getting any errors ? if so then upload here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess your Activity doesn't even get called... try adding the following lines to your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="yourpackage.ArtistsActivity" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Replace "yourpackage" with the name of your package and do the same with the corresponding action name within your `AlbumsActivity` and `SongsActivity`.

[More information on Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Comment: Doesn't work. The package is already defined at the top of the Manifest and secondly intent is created and assigned in HelloTabWidget.java. Not sure what I'm missing there

Comment: Yeah, now I know it was crap I wrote, the intent is class specific so you don't need those lines, sorry! Ahm, is your method name really `OnCreate` with an uppercase "o"? It should be `onCreate` with a lowercase "o"! Otherwise I can't find any error, I tried the exmaple and it worked out of the box.

Comment: Golden! My method name was indeed starting with an upper case. Thanks man, now I see my text in the tabs